# Access default web cam on windows8 using Media Foundation

Tags: c++11, ms-media-foundation

I'm building a multimedia application on window8 and I need to access the system default camera device (say there multiple web cams connected to the computer and I need to select the system default one). I'm using media foundation framework and cannot find such an API that tells me which is the default camera. It seems it can only return a list of devices connected to the computer (using the MFEnumDeviceSources(pAttributes, &ppDevices, &count) function). Among all the capture device attributes listed here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317915(v=vs.85).aspx ,

it seems there is no such an attribute specifying whether the device is a default one.

So how do I get the default device using Media Foundation ? If Media Foundation cannot achieve this, is there any other frameworks I can use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media Foundation does not have a concept of a default webcam.  I would suggest to provide a selector in the options, and default to the first device, and save any changed selections.  In fact, to get the default mic, you will not use Media Foundation.  Instead you will utilize `IMMDeviceEnumerator` and `IMMDevice` to get the default, and compare that to the found devices from Media Foundation.

Pertaining to other frameworks, I would stick with Media Foundation.  It is easy to use, and performs quite well. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. But it seems IMMDeviceEnumerator  only gives default audio device. Doea that mean there is no such a concept called "default" video device ?

Comment: Correct.  Windows does not currently have a concept of default webcam.  I believe OS X does.

Comment: But does that mean I'd better make sure both the audio and video devices come from the same device ? Say I connect a web cam to my desktop and it also has a mic, and I have to make sure both the audio and video devices default to that web cam ?

Comment: Let the user choose them separately.  The user may choose to use the microphone on their headset, and you wouldn't want to force them to use the mic on the webcam.

Comment: @CalvinHu - Does this answer your question, or is there more information I can provide?

Comment: Great.  Don't forget to mark the question as answered. (check the checkmark next to your favorite answer).  And I hope your project goes well.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I got another Media Foundation question. Do you know how video frame rate works with PROVARIANT structure ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899390/media-foundation-set-video-capture-frame-rate-using-propvariant-structure

Comment: I see that Roman provided an answer, however  I provided an additional answer hoping to help you.

Comment: You are welcome Calvin.  You may want to click the up arrow by any answers that you like or that helped you.  The same is true for questions.  Good luck with your project.