# Media Foundation set video capture frame rate using PROPVARIANT structure

Tags: c++, windows, com, ms-media-foundation

I'm writing a media foundation application where I need to set the capture frame rate for a video device. The function I'm writing is something like:

```
bool SetRequestedFrameRate(const size_t requestedFramesPerSecond);
```

where I pass a user-defined integer as the frame rate parameter. I'm following the code snippet on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485859(v=vs.85).aspx  :

```
PROPVARIANT var;
if (SUCCEEDED(pType->GetItem(MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX, &var)))
{
    hr = pType->SetItem(MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, var);

    PropVariantClear(&var);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    hr = pHandler->SetCurrentMediaType(pType);
}
```

Apparantly it uses the PROVARIANT structure to hold frame rate data. But how do I construct a PROVARIANT structure from my "const size_t requestedFramesPerSecond" parameter? If I already have a PROVARIANT that holds the frame rate, how do I retrieve the actual frame rate integer from it ?  Also, does COM provide a way to compare two PROVARIANT structures that represent frame rate ?

Please help, thank!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Roman pointed out, you can avoid dealing with the [PROPVARIANT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380072(v=vs.85).aspx) structure, by using the utility functions to access the [IMFAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms704598(v=vs.85).aspx) store.  However, 
as #7 points out on the [page you referenced](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485859(v=vs.85).aspx):

> 7. Query the media type for the MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX and MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN attributes. This values give the range of
>      supported frame rates. The device might support other frame rates
>      within this range.

Enumerate the native media types of the capture device, and simply select (choose one) and reuse the media type to [set the current media type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374667(v=vs.85).aspx).  Otherwise you will be frustrated with failed calls which do not match the capabilities of the capture device.  I discuss frame rates a bit and show how to enumerate the native media type [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30815015/get-all-supported-fps-values-of-a-camera-in-microsoft-media-foundation/30848315#30848315).  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I saw you used a IMFSourceReader object to get the underlying native media types, The IMFSourceReader also has a SetCurrentMediaType() method. So should I use it to set the mediaType or the one in the IMFMediaTypeHandler class ?  If I choose to call the SetCurrentMediaType() defined in IMFMediaTypeHandler class, then I believe I have to get a mediaTypeHandler first from a IMFMediaSource object. Is using SourceReader better than directly dealing with a IMFMediaSource ?

Comment: That depends on your project.  IMFMediaTypeHandler is necessary when you build a custom source or sink, or dealing with a specific stream descriptor.  If you are simply processing samples from a webcam or capture card, IMFSourceReader is quite simple to use, even if you are processing audio and video samples from an aggregate source.

Comment: Hi Jeff. I got a question regarding your comment. You said in order to set frame rate on for the output format I need to first list native media types and reuse one of them to reset the current media type. But let say I have chosen a native media type from the list, but its frame rate is different from the value I want to set, is it still legal to set frame rate on this type ?

Comment: No, unfortunately that generally doesn't work.  Are you using a webcam, capture card, or other?  What framerate are you looking for? Often times, a webcam will offer 30, 15, and some other frame rates at each resolution and format.  If you are using an older webcam, it is possible that it cannot produce 30fps (shutter speed, drivers, etc).

Comment: I'm using a webcam, but how do I decide which frame rates are supported by the devices?  I've looked at you previous post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30815015/get-all-supported-fps-values-of-a-camera-in-microsoft-media-foundation/30848315#30848315 , and you said we can do loop through all the possible media types. But for each media type, we call  MFGetAttributeRatio(mediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, &frameRate, &denominator); which only returns one frame rate. But what if this media type supports more than one frame rates? Where is second one returned?

Comment: I think you may have overlooked that it is a while loop.  It will loop until MF_E_NO_MORE_TYPES is returned.  Some webcams will have over 200 while early webcams only have 20 or so.

Comment: I have edited that answer, to include the output of an older webcam.

Answer (score 1):

[`MF_MT_FRAME_RATE` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms700140) is a pair of 32-bit integers representing numerator and denominator. `MFSetAttributeRatio` and friends are helpers to set/get the values in a friendly way. Using `PROVARIANT` you should handle it as a 64-bit `UINT64` value.

> The frame rate is expressed as a ratio. The upper 32 bits of the attribute value contain the numerator and the lower 32 bits contain the denominator. For example, if the frame rate is 30 frames per second (fps), the ratio is 30/1. If the frame rate is 29.97 fps, the ratio is 30,000/1001.

Comment: So if I use the MFSetAttributeRatio method, then I can avoid the PROVARIANT business right ?

Comment: Correct.  However I don't think you want to do it that way.  The best way is to enumerate the capture device's native media types, and set it to one that meets your desired characteristics.